# Azure mobile service/app android sdk google authentication - app goes to the background

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to implement google authentication in my android app which is connecting to an Azure Mobile service (app). I am calling MobileServiceClient.login method in the onCreate method of the activity.

```
_client.login("Google","{url_scheme}",1)
```

Everything works fine when I login for the first time. If I am already logged into google, app displays the dialog which navigates to the Mobile service's URL and goes back to the homescreen (means my **app goes to the background**). If I bring the app back to the foreground system calls onActivityResult method.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Logged in successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

If i am already logged into google the onActityResult never gets called until i bring the up to the foreground manually. If I log out of the google account in the browser and relaunch the app, the authentication dialog will prompt me for the email and password and after successful sign in onActivityResult is called.

I have configured the RedirectUrlActivity in the app manifest

```
   <activity android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.authentication.RedirectUrlActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data android:scheme="stocktracker"
                android:host="easyauth.callback"
                />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Dependencies for the customtabs library is also in place

```
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1'
```

I am using android sdk version 25 and mobile services sdk 3.3

```
compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-android:3.3.0@aar'
```

**Update**

I used the google sign in API and got the oauth token and passed to the mobile service and got it working. I don't like this approach as i am making 3 service calls, 1. to google to authenticate, 2. to google to get the oauth token, 3. to mobile service to authenticate. With the Google sign in option i am using the same approach of starting an intent and accessing the result in `onActivityResult' method, which works fine.

Comment: What's your real question? I don't know what means as you said "goes back to the homescreen (means my app goes to the background)".  Could you post more details? And please refer to the sample code in the offical tutorial of [Add authentication to the app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-users#add-authentication-to-the-app) and try again.

Comment: Yes i am using the Azure mobile app tutorial. What i meant by activity going to the background is after authenticating with google, my activity's on stop method is called. instead, it is expected to call onActivityResult. onActivityResult is called only when i bring the app to the foreground explicitly.   Below is how the events are happening in my app, i call _client.login , an Intent is shown, and redirected to a sign in page, sign in page redirects to google's sign in page and since i am already signed in the Intent is closed, and my app's onStop is called